# How do you convert LONG data to TIMESTAMP or VARCHAR2?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

**I need something like:**

```
SELECT PARTITION_NAME,
       to_char(LONG_TO_TIMESTAMP(HIGH_VALUE), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS HIGH_VAL
  FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS
 WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME'
```

**Output should look something like this:**

```
PARTITION_NAME         HIGH_VAL
----------------   --------------------
SOME_NAME          01/01/2010 00:00:00
```

**When I run:**

> SELECT PARTITION_NAME, HIGH_VALUE FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS

**It looks like:**

```
PARTITION_NAME         HIGH_VAL
----------------   --------------------
SOME_NAME          TIMESTAMP' 2010-01-01 00:00:00'
```

If I use `UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(HIGH_VALUE)`,
I end up getting an `ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype` error.

If I use `''||HIGH_VALUE` or `to_clob(HIGH_VALUE)` or `to_char(HIGH_VALUE)`,
I get an `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected [DATA_TYPE] got LONG` error

**My working function thanks to shobi:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_HIGH_VALUE_AS_DATE (
    p_TableName     IN VARCHAR2,
    p_PatitionName  IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN DATE
IS
   v_LongVal LONG;
BEGIN
    SELECT HIGH_VALUE INTO v_LongVal
      FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS
     WHERE TABLE_NAME = p_TableName
       AND PARTITION_NAME = p_PatitionName;

    RETURN TO_DATE(substr(v_LongVal, 11, 19), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
END GET_HIGH_VALUE_AS_DATE;
```

**SQL Looks like**

```
SELECT PARTITION_NAME, GET_HIGH_VALUE_AS_DATE(TABLE_NAME, PARTITION_NAME)
  FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS
 WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'TABLE_NAME'
   AND ROWNUM < 2;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to convert LONG columns is in PL/SQL. Look at the following example, which determines the length of the LONG field:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 10000;  
DECLARE
long_var LONG;
BEGIN
SELECT text_column INTO long_var
FROM table_with_long
WHERE rownum < 2;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The length is '||LENGTH(long_var));
END;
```

Basically, you define a variable as the LONG type, then SELECT the column INTO the variable. Finally, it is output to the user. SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 10000 allows spooling from the PUT_LINE to go to the screen.

You can use a similar method to select the LONG into a varchar field. The following example puts the first 2000 characters into TABLE_B, which for our purposes has one column, TEXT_FIELD:

```
DECLARE
   long_var LONG;
   var_var  VARCHAR2(2000);
   BEGIN
   SELECT text_column INTO long_var
   FROM table_with_long
   WHERE rownum < 2;
   var_var := substr(long_var,1,2000);
   INSERT INTO table_b
   VALUES (var_var);
   END;
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a good trick to do this using dynamic sql ( `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` )

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
     l_date   DATE;
BEGIN
     FOR r IN (
          SELECT partition_name,high_value
            FROM user_tab_partitions
          WHERE table_name = 'MYTABLE'
     ) LOOP
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :v := ' || r.high_value || '; END;' 
             USING  OUT l_date;
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r.partition_name||','|| l_date);
     END LOOP;
END;
/
```

This produces an output of the form

```
SYS_P601452,19-10-18  --(partition_name,high_value)
SYS_P601451,18-10-18
SYS_P601453,20-10-18
SYS_P601454,21-10-18
SYS_P601455,22-10-18
..
..
```

Here I used a `DATE` type partitioned column. You may use a `TIMESTAMP` variable.

Answer (score 1):

It would also be possible to do the following:

```
CREATE TABLE long_to_clob
( partition_name VARCHAR2(30)
, high_value_clob CLOB
, high_value_text VARCHAR2(4000)
);

INSERT INTO long_to_clob (partition_name, high_value_clob)
SELECT partition_name, TO_LOB(high_value)
  FROM user_tab_partitions;

UPDATE long_to_clob
   SET high_value_text = DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(high_value_clob, 1, 4000);
```

The only caveat with using TO_LOB is that it must be used in an INSERT statement as above. On the other hand there are fewer restrictions on using the DBMS_LOB package. Obviously once you have the value in a VARCHAR2 column you can do anything you want with it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me (and should work on 11g and up).
The partition table is converted to XML and back to rows and columns.

```
SELECT
  pn PARTITION_NAME,
  TO_DATE(SUBSTR(hv,12,10),'YYYY-MM-DD') HIGH_VALUE
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM XMLTABLE('/ROWSET/ROW'
        PASSING XMLTYPE(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('SELECT partition_name, high_value FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS WHERE table_name=''HERE-GOES-YOUR-TABLE-NAME'''))
        COLUMNS 
        pn VARCHAR2(128) PATH 'PARTITION_NAME',
        hv VARCHAR2(32) PATH 'HIGH_VALUE'
    )
)
WHERE hv LIKE 'TIMESTAMP''%'
ORDER BY HIGH_VALUE DESC;
```

If you really need TIMESTAMP, replace `TO_DATE(...) HIGH_VALUE` to `TO_TIMESTAMP(SUBSTR(hv,12,19),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') HIGH_VALUE`.

Replace `HERE-GOES-YOUR-TABLE-NAME` with your table name.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  PARTITION_NAME,
  high_value
FROM XMLTABLE(
'/ROWSET/ROW'
PASSING
  DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXMLTYPE
    (Q'~
select
   p.partition_name,
   p.high_value
from user_tab_partitions p
 where table_name = 'MYTABLE'
order by partition_position
~'
)
COLUMNS PARTITION_NAME, HIGH_VALUE
);
```

Comment: Please avoid code only answer and provide some explanation

Comment: Also, please specify which version of Oracle this works for.